# Parse HTML using grep to CSV

Tags: html, linux, bash, csv, grep

I have the html file which included information

```html
<li>
<a title="Title_01" href="http://mysite.ru/test/portal/doc/#number=ABC01" target="_blank"><span class="i">ABC01  01/02    </span>(2006.01)</a>
</li>

<li>
<a title="Title_02" href="http://mysite.ru/test/portal/doc/#number=ABC02" target="_blank"><span class="i">ABC02  02/02    </span>(2006.01)</a>
</li>



<p>(73) Name(test):<b>
<br>MY TEST ORGANIZATION (TT)</b>
</p>
```

I can do parse data with command grep and after manually connect data into Excel

```
grep "number=" *.html > tt.txt
```

But is there some method to do it with grep that I will have the result into csv file such like that

```
    MY TEST ORGANIZATION, ABC01
    MY TEST ORGANIZATION, ABC02
```

Comment: In your desired result example is 'MY TEST ORGANIZATION' the name of the html file that ABC01 and ABC02 were found following "number="? Or is it just the the bold text inside a paragraph following the match? Or . . .

Comment: These sections are inside in one html-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can do better with awk, but, if you need a fast answer, this works:

```
grep "number=" file | sed 's/number=/MY TEST ORGANIZATION, /g;s/"//g' | cut -d# -f2
```

result:

```
MY TEST ORGANIZATION, ABC01
MY TEST ORGANIZATION, ABC02
```

Comment: or using perl: 
perl -nle 's/\"//g;/number=\K([^ ]+)/ && print "MY TEST ORGANIZATION, $1"' file

Comment: Thank you. On perl also nicce

Answer (score 1):

**awk -F  "[>|\"|=]"   '/number=/  {print  "MY TEST ORGANIZATION, "$7}'  file**

MY TEST ORGANIZATION,   ABC01

MY TEST ORGANIZATION,   ABC02

with awk it can be doing so!